# PHP Find specific domain link in string

Tags: php, hyperlink, get, expression

I need to find a url in text starts with domain zippyshare and put it in the var. I know that i must use regular expression but i don't have idea to make it. Lets say that we have 3 links in text

`Facebook: https://facebook.com/pumpsquadofficial Instagram: https://instagram.com/pump_squadpl DOWNLOAD MP3: http://www42.zippyshare.com/v/d6LnGjH8/file.html`

and i need to find and put this link "www.42.zippyshare.com/v/blahblahblah" into `<a href="$link">`. Do you have any idea how to make it? Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague... Obviously you can extract the link looking for that domain name:

```
<?php
$data = <<<LINKS
Facebook: https://facebook.com/pumpsquadofficial Instagram: https://instagram.com/pump_squadpl DOWNLOAD MP3: http://www42.zippyshare.com/v/d6LnGjH8/file.html Some more text
LINKS;
preg_match('~(http://\w+\.zippyshare\.com/[^\s]+)~', $data, $tokens);
echo sprintf('<a href="%s">', $tokens[1]);
```

The output obviously is:

```
<a href="http://www42.zippyshare.com/v/d6LnGjH8/file.html">
```

I think however it makes sense to invest a few moments into the definition of what information you actually can rely on to extract that link. Is the domain really always that `zippyshare.com`? Or maybe you need to always extract the link following the `DOWNLOAD MP3`?

Comment: That's what i've looked for! Thank you so much! Yeah i wanted to output link zippyshare.com, domain is always the same.